# Android SQLite Column Not Found Error When Executing Raw Query

Tags: android, database, sqlite, simplecursoradapter, sqliteopenhelper

I am making an android app that searches for restaurants in a SQLite database. I currently use a custom loader (that I found online) to load a cursor from the database and then take that cursor and populate a listview with a SimpleCursorAdapter. I want all the data to be bound but only the name of the restaurant to be displayed (because when I click on a list item I want to get all the data and send it to a new activity that displays the data). If I specify the restaurant name and restaurant type as the search parameters, I run the raw query:

```
 "SELECT * FROM Restaurant WHERE name = " + name + " AND rType = " + restaurantType;
```

in my SQLiteCursorLoader class and I get an error saying that the column rType does not exist, even thought I know the column exists in the Restuarant table. It seems that I get this error when I have two WHERE clauses in my query but this does not happen when I have one WHERE clause. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated! Here is my code:

RestuarantSearchResultsActivity:

```
package com.studentapplication;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class RestaurantSearchResultsActivity extends ListActivity implements
LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;
Bundle searchParameters;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Log.w("CoolBeans", "Results Activity Created");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
    //setContentView(R.layout.restaurant_search_results);

    Bundle searchParameters = getIntent().getExtras();
    String n = searchParameters.getString("name");
    Log.i("0)", n);


    //first N columns should match toViews first N views
    String[] fromColumns = {getString(R.string.database_column_name),
                           getString(R.string.database_column_restaurant_type),
                           getString(R.string.database_column_phone_number),
                           getString(R.string.database_column_address),
               getString(R.string.database_column_csz),
               getString(R.string.database_column_brief_description),
               getString(R.string.database_column_url),
               getString(R.string.database_column_price)};

    int[] toViews = {android.R.id.text1};

    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter( getApplicationContext(),
                        this.getListView().getId(),
                        null,
                            fromColumns,
                        toViews,
                        0);
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, searchParameters, this);       
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle searchParameters) {
    Log.i("3)", "Correct Loader Being Built");
    return new SQLiteCursorLoader(getApplicationContext(),
            databaseHelper,
            searchParameters,
            null);

}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(data);

}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(null);

}

@Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    Cursor myCursor = (Cursor)l.getItemAtPosition(position);
    if(l.isItemChecked(position) == true)
    {
        l.setItemChecked(position, false);
        //shut down previously selected item details

    }
    else
    {
        l.setItemChecked(position, true);

        //start previously selected item details

    }
}


}
```

SQLiteCursorLoader:

```
package com.studentapplication;

import java.io.FileDescriptor;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Arrays;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class SQLiteCursorLoader extends AbstractCursorLoader
{
SQLiteOpenHelper db=null;
String rawQuery=null;
String[] args=null;

/**
 * Creates a fully-specified SQLiteCursorLoader. See
 * {@link SQLiteDatabase#rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase, String, String[])
 * SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery()} for documentation on the
 * meaning of the parameters. These will be passed as-is
 * to that call.
 */
public SQLiteCursorLoader(Context context, SQLiteOpenHelper db, Bundle
    searchParameters, String[] args)
{
    super(context);
    this.db=db;
    this.rawQuery=createQuery(searchParameters);
    this.args=args;
}

private String createQuery(Bundle searchParameters) {
    String name = "\'";
    name = name + searchParameters.getString("name");
    name = name + "\'";
    int price = searchParameters.getInt("price");
    String restaurantType = "\'";
    restaurantType = restaurantType +
            searchParameters.getString("restaurant_type");
    restaurantType = restaurantType + "\'";

    //String dist = searchParameters.getString("dist");

    String theQuery = "";

    if(!name.equals("\'\'"))
    {
        if(!restaurantType.equals("\'_\'"))
        {
            theQuery = "SELECT * FROM Restaurant WHERE name 
= "+ name + " AND rType = " + restaurantType;
        }
        else if(price != 0)
        {
            theQuery = "SELECT * FROM Restaurant WHERE name = " + name
+ " AND price = " + ((Integer)price).toString();
        }
        else
        {
            theQuery="SELECT * FROM Restaurant WHERE name = " + name;
        }
    }
    else if(!restaurantType.equals("\'\'"))
    {
        theQuery = "SELECT * FROM Restaurant WHERE type = " +
restaurantType + " SORT BY name"; 
    }
    else if(price != 0)
    {
        theQuery="SELECT * FROM Restaurant WHERE price=" + price + " SORT
BY name";
    }



    return theQuery;
}


/**
 * Runs on a worker thread and performs the actual
 * database query to retrieve the Cursor.
 */
@Override
protected Cursor buildCursor()
{
    return(db.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(rawQuery, args));
}

/**
 * Writes a semi-user-readable roster of contents to
 * supplied output.
 */
@Override
public void dump(String prefix, FileDescriptor fd, PrintWriter writer, String[]
    args)
{
    super.dump(prefix, fd, writer, args);
    writer.print(prefix);
    writer.print("rawQuery=");
    writer.println(rawQuery);
    writer.print(prefix);
    writer.print("args=");
    writer.println(Arrays.toString(args));
}

public void insert(String table, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues values)
{
    new InsertTask(this).execute(db, table, nullColumnHack, values);
}

public void update(String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[]
    whereArgs)
{
    new UpdateTask(this).execute(db, table, values, whereClause, whereArgs);
}

public void replace(String table, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues values)
{
    new ReplaceTask(this).execute(db, table, nullColumnHack, values);
}

public void delete(String table, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)
{
    new DeleteTask(this).execute(db, table, whereClause, whereArgs);
}

public void execSQL(String sql, Object[] bindArgs)
{
    new ExecSQLTask(this).execute(db, sql, bindArgs);
}

//Private Classes

private class InsertTask extends ContentChangingTask<Object, Void, Void>
{
    InsertTask(SQLiteCursorLoader loader)
    {
        super(loader);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Object... params)
    {
        SQLiteOpenHelper db=(SQLiteOpenHelper)params[0];
        String table=(String)params[1];
        String nullColumnHack=(String)params[2];
        ContentValues values=(ContentValues)params[3];

        db.getWritableDatabase().insert(table, nullColumnHack, values);

        return(null);
    }
}

private class UpdateTask extends ContentChangingTask<Object, Void, Void>
{
    UpdateTask(SQLiteCursorLoader loader)
    {
        super(loader);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Object... params)
    {
        SQLiteOpenHelper db=(SQLiteOpenHelper)params[0];
        String table=(String)params[1];
        ContentValues values=(ContentValues)params[2];
        String where=(String)params[3];
        String[] whereParams=(String[])params[4];

        db.getWritableDatabase().update(table, values, where, whereParams);

        return(null);
    }
}

private class ReplaceTask extends ContentChangingTask<Object, Void, Void>
{
    ReplaceTask(SQLiteCursorLoader loader)
    {
        super(loader);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Object... params)
    {
        SQLiteOpenHelper db=(SQLiteOpenHelper)params[0];
        String table=(String)params[1];
        String nullColumnHack=(String)params[2];
        ContentValues values=(ContentValues)params[3];

        db.getWritableDatabase().replace(table, nullColumnHack, values);

        return(null);
    }
}

private class DeleteTask extends ContentChangingTask<Object, Void, Void>
{
    DeleteTask(SQLiteCursorLoader loader)
    {
        super(loader);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Object... params)
    {
        SQLiteOpenHelper db=(SQLiteOpenHelper)params[0];
        String table=(String)params[1];
        String where=(String)params[2];
        String[] whereParams=(String[])params[3];

        db.getWritableDatabase().delete(table, where, whereParams);

        return(null);
    }
}

private class ExecSQLTask extends ContentChangingTask<Object, Void, Void>
{
    ExecSQLTask(SQLiteCursorLoader loader)
    {
        super(loader);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Object... params)
    {
        SQLiteOpenHelper db=(SQLiteOpenHelper)params[0];
        String sql=(String)params[1];
        Object[] bindParams=(Object[])params[2];

        db.getWritableDatabase().execSQL(sql, bindParams);

     return(null);
    }
}
}
```

AbstractCursorLoader:

```
package com.studentapplication;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.AsyncTaskLoader;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Build;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
abstract public class AbstractCursorLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<Cursor> {

abstract protected Cursor buildCursor();
Cursor lastCursor=null;

public AbstractCursorLoader(Context context) {
  super(context);
}

/** 
 * Runs on a worker thread, loading in our data. Delegates
 * the real work to concrete subclass' buildCursor() method. 
 */
@Override
public Cursor loadInBackground() {
  Cursor cursor=buildCursor();

  if (cursor!=null) {
    // Ensure the cursor window is filled
    cursor.getCount();
  }

  return(cursor);
}

/**
 * Runs on the UI thread, routing the results from the
 * background thread to whatever is using the Cursor
 * (e.g., a CursorAdapter).
 */
@Override
public void deliverResult(Cursor cursor) {
  if (isReset()) {
    // An async query came in while the loader is stopped
    if (cursor!=null) {
      cursor.close();
    }

    return;
  }

  Cursor oldCursor=lastCursor;
  lastCursor=cursor;

  if (isStarted()) {
    super.deliverResult(cursor);
  }

  if (oldCursor!=null && oldCursor!=cursor && !oldCursor.isClosed()) {
    oldCursor.close();
  }
}

/**
 * Starts an asynchronous load of the list data.
 * When the result is ready the callbacks will be called
 * on the UI thread. If a previous load has been completed
 * and is still valid the result may be passed to the
 * callbacks immediately.
 * 
 * Must be called from the UI thread.
 */
@Override
protected void onStartLoading() {
  if (lastCursor!=null) {
    deliverResult(lastCursor);
  }

  if (takeContentChanged() || lastCursor==null) {
    forceLoad();
  }
}

/**
* Must be called from the UI thread, triggered by a
* call to stopLoading().
*/
@Override
protected void onStopLoading() {
  // Attempt to cancel the current load task if possible.
  cancelLoad();
}

/**
 * Must be called from the UI thread, triggered by a
 * call to cancel(). Here, we make sure our Cursor
 * is closed, if it still exists and is not already closed.
 */
@Override
public void onCanceled(Cursor cursor) {
  if (cursor!=null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
    cursor.close();
  }
}

/**
 * Must be called from the UI thread, triggered by a
 * call to reset(). Here, we make sure our Cursor
 * is closed, if it still exists and is not already closed.
 */
@Override
protected void onReset() {
  super.onReset();

  // Ensure the loader is stopped
  onStopLoading();

  if (lastCursor!=null && !lastCursor.isClosed()) {
    lastCursor.close();
  }

  lastCursor=null;
  }
  }
```

DatabaseHelper:

```
package com.studentapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "LOCAL_DATABASE";

// table Names
private static final String TABLE_Restaurant = "Restaurant";
private static final String TABLE_Coupon = "Coupon";
private static final String TABLE_Linker = "Linker";

//restaurant columns
private static final String R_Name = "name";
private static final String R_Description = "description";
private static final String R_Address = "address";
private static final String R_CSZ = "CSZ";
private static final String R_URL = "url";
private static final String R_Price = "price";
private static final String R_Type = "rType";
private static final String R_ID = "_id";

//coupon columns
private static final String C_ID = "_id";
private static final String C_NAME = "name";
private static final String C_Description = "description";

//linker table columns
private static final String r_id = "r_id";
private static final String c_id = "c_id";
private static final String date = "date";
private static final String l_id = "l_id";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

}

public DatabaseHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
        int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_Restaurant_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_Restaurant + "( "
            + R_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            + R_Name + " TEXT NOT NULL, " 
            + R_Type + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + R_Address + " TEXT NOT NULL, " 
            + R_CSZ + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + R_Description + " TEXT NOT NULL, " 
            + R_URL + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + R_Price +" INTEGER NOT NULL"
            + " )";

    String CREATE_Coupon_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_Coupon + "("
            + C_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " 
            + C_NAME + " TEXT, "
            + C_Description + " TEXT"
            + ")";

    String CREATE_Linker_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_Linker + "("
            + r_id + " INTEGER, " 
            + c_id + " INTEGER, " 
            + date + " DATE, "
            + l_id + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            + "FOREIGN KEY(r_id) REFERENCES Restaurant(_id), "
            + "FOREIGN KEY(c_id) REFERENCES Coupon(_id) )";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_Restaurant_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_Coupon_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_Linker_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_Restaurant);
    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

}
```

Stack Trace:

```
04-23 13:47:29.691: E/SQLiteLog(2600): (1) no such column: rType
04-23 13:47:29.691: W/dalvikvm(2600): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught
    exception (group=0x40a13300)
04-23 13:47:29.852: E/AndroidRuntime(2600): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
04-23 13:47:29.852: E/AndroidRuntime(2600): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error
    occured while executing doInBackground()
04-23 13:47:29.852: E/AndroidRuntime(2600):     at
    android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
04-23 13:47:29.852: E/AndroidRuntime(2600):     at
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
04-23 13:47:29.852: E/AndroidRuntime(2600):     at
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
04-23 13:47:29.852: E/AndroidRuntime(2600):     at
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
04-23 13:47:29.852: E/AndroidRuntime(2600):     at
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-23 13:47:29.852: E/AndroidRuntime(2600):     at
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
04-23 13:47:29.852: E/AndroidRuntime(2600):     at
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
04-23 13:47:29.852: E/AndroidRuntime(2600):     at
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-23 13:47:29.852: E/AndroidRuntime(2600): Caused by:
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: rType (code 1): , while
    compiling: SELECT * FROM Restaurant WHERE name = 'RName' AND rType = 'Fancy'
04-23 13:47:29.852: E/AndroidRuntime(2600):     at
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
04-23 13:47:29.852: E/AndroidRuntime(2600):     at
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement
    (SQLiteConnection.java:882)
04-23 13:47:29.852: E/AndroidRuntime(2600):     at
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
04-23 13:47:29.852: E/AndroidRuntime(2600):     at
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
04-23 13:47:29.852: E/AndroidRuntime(2600):     at
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
04-23 13:47:29.852: E/AndroidRuntime(2600):     at
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
04-23 13:47:29.852: E/AndroidRuntime(2600):     at
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query
    (SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
04-23 13:47:29.852: E/AndroidRuntime(2600):     at
   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
04-23 13:47:29.852: E/AndroidRuntime(2600):     at
   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
04-23 13:47:29.852: E/AndroidRuntime(2600):     at
    com.studentapplication.SQLiteCursorLoader.buildCursor(SQLiteCursorLoader.java:88)
04-23 13:47:29.852: E/AndroidRuntime(2600):     at
    com.studentapplication.AbstractCursorLoader.loadInBackground
    (AbstractCursorLoader.java:24)
04-23 13:47:29.852: E/AndroidRuntime(2600):     at
    com.studentapplication.AbstractCursorLoader.loadInBackground
    (AbstractCursorLoader.java:1)
04-23 13:47:29.852: E/AndroidRuntime(2600):     at
    android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:301)
04-23 13:47:29.852: E/AndroidRuntime(2600):     at
    android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:68)
04-23 13:47:29.852: E/AndroidRuntime(2600):     at
    android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:56)
04-23 13:47:29.852: E/AndroidRuntime(2600):     at
    android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-23 13:47:29.852: E/AndroidRuntime(2600):     at
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
04-23 13:47:29.852: E/AndroidRuntime(2600):     ... 4 more
04-23 13:47:29.902: W/ActivityManager(161):   Force finishing activity
    com.studentapplication/.RestaurantSearchResultsActivity
04-23 13:47:29.902: W/WindowManager(161): Failure taking screenshot for (266x425) to
    layer 21020
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace of your error. Also, bear in mind that `"SELECT * FROM Restaurant WHERE name = " + name + " AND rType = " + restaurantType; ` is not going to be a valid query unless `name` and `restaurantType` are numbers, as they are not quoted. And having "two WHERE clauses in [your] query" is not going to be valid SQL syntax either.

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for looking over my question. I do have them quoted. If you look at my SQLiteCursorLoader class in the createQuery method, I set up the Strings to start with ' and end with '. I'll post the stack trace momentarily.

Comment: Also, when you say to WHERE clauses isn't a valid syntax, do you mean that "WHERE name = " + name + " AND rType = " + restaurantType; isn't valid?

Comment: That's not "two WHERE clauses". That is one `WHERE` clause, as there is only one `WHERE`. Rather than manually quoting stuff yourself, please use query binding, with `?` placeholders and a `String[]` of values as the second parameter to `rawQuery()`. Beyond that, uninstall (or clear data) on your app and run your app again, in case the issue is that you modified your database schema and did not have `rType` as a column before.

Comment: Ok, I put this into the buildCursor method:

return(db.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Restaurant WHERE name = ? AND rType = ?", new String[]{"\'RName\'", "\'Fancy\'"}));

and I still get the rType column not found error. So I guess I might have to clear/uninstall the data like you said. I'm not sure how to do that with Eclipse. Would I just have to "Clean" the project?

Comment: THAT'S THE TICKET!!! THANK YOU CommonsWare!!! I just uninstalled the database and it worked! I would have NEVER thought to do that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In production, when you modify the schema of your database, you bump the schema version number you pass to the `SQLiteOpenHelper` constructor, so `SQLiteOpenHelper` will call `onUpgrade()` and affect the change.

In development, you can do that too if you wish. But, it's easy to forget that. Hence, if your database structure does not seem to be matching expectations, either:

- Bump that schema version number, to force an `onUpgrade()` call, or
- Wipe out the existing database, via an uninstall, "Clear Data" from your app's entry in Settings, etc., to force a call to `onCreate()` of your `SQLiteOpenHelper`