# No Column named found in table sqlite

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

My code is correct is assume but even though it gives error coloumn not found for _pay_mode :

**LOGCAT :**

```
08-20 05:22:05.398: D/Reading:(17403): Reading all contacts..
08-20 05:22:05.539: D/income(17403): table created with price type date description pay_mode
08-20 05:22:35.164: E/Database(17403): Error inserting income
08-20 05:22:35.164: E/Database(17403): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table income has no column named pay_mode: , while compiling: INSERT INTO income(pay_mode, price, date, type, description) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
08-20 05:22:35.164: E/Database(17403):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
08-20 05:22:35.164: E/Database(17403):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
08-20 05:22:35.164: E/Database(17403):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
08-20 05:22:35.164: E/Database(17403):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
08-20 05:22:35.164: E/Database(17403):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:41)
08-20 05:22:35.164: E/Database(17403):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1151)
08-20 05:22:35.164: E/Database(17403):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1571)
08-20 05:22:35.164: E/Database(17403):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1428)
08-20 05:22:35.164: E/Database(17403):  at com.parth.targetthebudget.DatabaseHandler.addContact(DatabaseHandler.java:81)
08-20 05:22:35.164: E/Database(17403):  at com.parth.targetthebudget.Add_Income.onClick(Add_Income.java:58)
08-20 05:22:35.164: E/Database(17403):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
08-20 05:22:35.164: E/Database(17403):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
08-20 05:22:35.164: E/Database(17403):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-20 05:22:35.164: E/Database(17403):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-20 05:22:35.164: E/Database(17403):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-20 05:22:35.164: E/Database(17403):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
08-20 05:22:35.164: E/Database(17403):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-20 05:22:35.164: E/Database(17403):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-20 05:22:35.164: E/Database(17403):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
08-20 05:22:35.164: E/Database(17403):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
08-20 05:22:35.164: E/Database(17403):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

***OnCreate and OnUpgrade methods :***

```
// Creating Tables
    @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            String CREATE_INCOME_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + TABLE_INCOME + "("
                    + KEY_PRICE + "REAL,"  
                    + KEY_TYPE + "TEXT,"
                    + KEY_DATE + "TEXT," 
                    + KEY_DESCRIPTION + "TEXT," 
                    + KEY_PAY_MODE + "TEXT"
                    +")";
            db.execSQL(CREATE_INCOME_TABLE);
            Log.d(TABLE_INCOME, "table created with "+ KEY_PRICE +" "+ KEY_TYPE +" "
                    + KEY_DATE +" " + KEY_DESCRIPTION +" " + KEY_PAY_MODE);
        }

        // Upgrading database
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // Drop older table if existed
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_INCOME);

            // Create tables again
            onCreate(db);
        }
```

I had tried changing **database version** or **deleting my app and then re-install it** after studying these answers :

[Android SQLite Column Not Found Error When Executing Raw Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16175237/android-sqlite-column-not-found-error-when-executing-raw-query)

[SQLite android column not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12678789/sqlite-android-column-not-found)

But still not getting solution.!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that

```
KEY_PAY_MODE + "TEXT"
```

is `pay_modeTEXT`. Space shortage?

Also, could it be that the `CREATE TABLE` is not processed at all if it already exists? Did you try explicitly `DROP TABLE` or `DROP DATABASE` just in case?

(Note: I know nothing of Android platform, all these are general SQL ideas)

Comment: And not just that column, but all the others too!

Comment: @MH: Yup, I thought that would be obvious :)

Comment: Got it dude!! Such a silly one :( But OK I am learning :) Thank you so much.

Comment: @Amadan: Better safe than sorry. :)